# Flex & Bison Segmenation fault

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I to make a compiler and I use flex and bison for that.
I'm implementing the boolean comparision. But I have an error when bison goes into my token COMP.

I have declared like that :

```
("==")|(">=")|("<=")|("!=")|(">")|("<")
{
   sscanf(yytext,"%s",yylval.svalcmp); return COMP;
}
```

In bison my gramar is :

```
ExpBool :
  Exp COMP Exp { printf("TEST= %s \n",$2); /*comp_exp_temp($2);*/} 
| Exp BOPE Exp
| NEGATION Exp 
;
```

My union :

```
%union {
  char cval;
  char * sval;
  char * svalt;
  char * svalcmp;
  char svalas;
  char * svalds;
  int signedint;
  int usint;
}
```

and token decaring :

```
%token <svalcmp> COMP
```

Bison performs the first Exp but when it reads the COMP, I get a Segmenation fault.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: You need to show a bit more code (in particular the code that creates the `yylval` union), but chances are that you have a plain `char *` in there that you never set to point anywhere valid.

Comment: I have added my union code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use a different style in the lexer, so can't validate that the (...)|(...)... syntax is correct.  However, what is your union associated with yylval?  Is svalcmp a buffer or just a pointer?  If it's a buffer, you probably should constrain the scanf format by a length.  If it's just a pointer, you've probably hosed memory, and maybe hit a null pointer crash.

If you bring it up in GDB, attach a backtrace, and print yylval

Comment: If it's a char *, then the sscanf is writing to some random location of memory.  Some of the time, it is writable memory (you are scribbling on some other variable, your stack, the heap, something); other times, it may be something that is an illegal address (such as 0).  So, when it appears to work (ie, not crash), you have written to memory and later access it successfully (although something else may later crash as a result).  When you SEGV, it's because it's an invalid address.

Comment: If you can guarantee the size being never more than 3 bytes (the two bytes and a null), I would make svalcmp a char[3], and you should work fine.

Comment: I have convert my char * to a sample char tab. Now it's work fine. Thanks :)